# Whitelisting ports for detection in rkhunter

Tags: server, rkhunter

I'm trying to figure out in the `rkhunter` config how I can whitelist the detection of certain ports, such as ports used for IRCds, and other ports which I have for services which run on non-standard ports.

Does anyone know how to configure this so that `rkhunter` does not throw warnings about detecting the ports I wish to whitelist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You edit `/etc/rkhunter.conf`

```
# command line
sudo -e /etc/rkhunter.conf

# graphical
gksu gedit /etc/rkhunter.conf
```

Under the `WHITELIST_PORTS` section , add your whitelist. The configuration file has examples.

```
# Syntax /full/path/to/binary Protocol:port
# Protocol = TCP / UDP 
# You may use wildcards

PORT_WHITELIST=”/usr/sbin/privoxy TCP:8118″

#for multiple binaries / ports , list them as per the config file
PORT_WHITELIST="/usr/sbin/privoxy /usr/sbin/squid TCP:8118 TCP:3128"

# Alternate
PORT_WHITELIST="* TCP:22 TCP:80 TCP:443 TCP:8080"
```

Comment: well i should have posted to my own question here stating an issue...  there actually was a bug in the version I was using many eons ago.  Turns out they didnt process the list correctly in that version.  11.04 does not have this bug :P  (marked as answer because it does provide the config examples)

Answer (score 1):

The response from @Panther is correct. However you can also white-list whole path of executable. Example:

- White-list all open ports for executable **/usr/sbin/squid**

`PORT_PATH_WHITELIST=/usr/sbin/squid`

- White-list TCP port **3801** for executable **/usr/sbin/squid**

`PORT_PATH_WHITELIST=/usr/sbin/squid:TCP:3801`

All this with additional explanation is written in [rkhunter.conf](https://sources.debian.org/src/rkhunter/1.4.2-6+deb9u1/files/rkhunter.conf/#L925) file.

P.S.: I just bumped into this and I feel that somebody can benefit from it in the future.